# Scatter plot with ggplot with different colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have my data which is shown as below:

```
X   Y
1.92    0.79
6.80    0.55
4.53    -2.08
-1.13   -5.69
-5.60   -6.21
2.87    7.34
6.93    1.68
```

I want to plot a regular scatter plot with different colors for positive points and negative points. How do I do this using ggplot ? Thanks

EDIT:
This is what I attempted so far:

```
dat_input<-read.table("test.txt", header=TRUE)
shoot_input<-gather(dat_input, factor_key = TRUE)
ggplot(dat_input,  aes(x=shoot_input[1:7,2], y= shoot_input[8:14,2], color=key)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Updated my question. WIth this, I am getting the error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'key' not found

Comment: Do you define "negative point" as being negative in X, Y, either, or both?

Comment: Basically, if I plot these points in the 4 quadrants, the 1st quadrant will have all positives (so all points as Red, so both +ves), 3rd quadrant (both -ves, blue) and the rest can be a default color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::case_when` to make a new column in the data.frame with the information on positive columns

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat_input <- read_table2("X   Y
1.92    0.79
6.80    0.55
4.53    -2.08
-1.13   -5.69
-5.60   -6.21
2.87    7.34
6.93    1.68")

dat_input <- dat_input %>% 
  mutate(positives = case_when(
    X > 0 & Y > 0 ~ "Both positive",
    X < 0 & Y < 0 ~ "Both negative",
    TRUE ~ "One positive"
  ))

ggplot(dat_input, aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = positives)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>